# How do you define your own state monad using scalaz?

Tags: scala, monads, scalaz, monad-transformers, state-monad

So I'm trying to define my own state monad by extending the `Monad` trait in scalaz. I know I'm reinventing the wheel, but I'm trying to learn more about scala and scalaz. My code is as follows:

```
package pure
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

object StateUtil {
  sealed trait State[S, A] { self =>
    def unit[A](a : A) : State[S, A] = StateM(s => (a, s))
    def runState(s : S) : (A, S) 
    def flatMap[B](f : A => State[S, B]) : State[S, B] = {
        val stateFun = (s : S) => {
          val (v, ss) = self.runState(s)
          f(v).runState(ss)
        }
        StateM(stateFun)
    }

    def map[B](f : A => B) : State[S, B] = flatMap(f andThen (unit _))
  }

  case class StateM[S, A](run : S => (A, S)) extends State[S, A] {
    def runState(s : S) : (A, S) = run(s)
  }

  class StateMonad[S]() extends Monad[({type St[A] = State[S, A]})#St] {
    def point[A](a : => A) : State[S, A] = StateM(s => (a, s))
    def bind[A, B](prev : State[S, A])(f : A => State[S, B]) : State[S, B] = prev flatMap f
    def apply[A](a : => A) : State[S, A] = point(a)
  }

  def put[S](s : S) : State[S, Unit] = StateM(_ => ((), s))

  def get[S]: State[S, S] = StateM(s => (s, s))


}
```

I'm trying to achieve the same behavior as that of the haskell function called `stackyStack`(the code is in the comment below). The problem is that the `get` method returns something of type `State[S, S]`, and I cannot use the scalaz's `>>=` operator. But I've no idea how to make that work.

And I'm not even sure if this is how you define your own monads using scalaz. And if I want to replicate the `do` syntax in scala, what else am I missing?

```
object main {
  import pure.StateUtil._

  /*
   *  stackyStack :: State Stack ()  
        stackyStack = do  
          stackNow <- get  
          if stackNow == [1,2,3]  
            then put [8,3,1]  
            else put [9,2,1]  
   */
   type Stack = List[Int]
   def stacky : State[Stack, Unit] = {
     // won't compile, because get returns something of type State[S, S],            
     // and the bind operator is not a memeber of the State trait I defined
     get >>=
   }


}
```